# Neutrino Oscillation and FCNC

Tags: mass, standard-model, oscillators, neutrinos, beyond-the-standard-model

We know that in the Standard Model (SM) neutrinos are massless. But the discovery of neutrino oscillation suggests that neutrinos must have masses because only then there will be a mass basis for neutrinos and neutrinos will mix among each other through the **PMNS matrix** $U_\text{PMNS}$. Now my question is:

**Couldn't we explain the neutrino oscillation through the Flavor Changing Neutral Currents (FCNC) or some other Beyond-SM phenomena so that neutrinos remain massless?**

Comment: What mechanism/notional diagram would you have in mind? If $\nu_e,\nu_\mu,\nu_\tau$ were degenerate null-mass eigenstates, what would make them change?

Comment: A BSM interaction of kind S$\nu_e\nu_\mu$, where S is some scalar particle.

Comment: It all depends on whether your *S* has a v.e.v. or not. If yes, then you have a  mass matrix, to diagonalize, so your neutrinos are not massless to start with, *just like the SM neutrinos*, which may well ***have a mass*** through standard SM Yukawa couplings. If someone starts bloviating to you that the SM does not allow neutrino masses, walk away. Run!